# How do I make the keypad Enter key work?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS on a Macbook Pro (I think it's a `Macbook11,4`).

I recently got a Logitech G413 Silver keyboard.  Everything just works, even the Media keys... except the keypad ENTER key.  I've been searching around and reading man pages and haven't yet found an answer that's helped me.

Several answers refer to using `xmodmap` to do this, but newer answers indicate that this isn't used anymore, and that instead I should edit a file found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.  The problem with *that* suggestion, is that my input method on the system bar is named `en1` (for the laptop keyboard) and `en2` (for the Logitech G413), and the `symbols/` directory does not contain anything resembling `en`, anywhere.  I tried:

```
MacBookPro:~$ ls -R /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ | grep -i en
parens
```

Following some more searching, I happened across the idea that perhaps editing the file called `pc` in that folder might work, as there seems to be some hierarchical configuration loading going on.  I'm left guessing as to what exactly that means.

Someone suggested I run xev, hit they key in question and post the result.  Here it is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x16e, subw 0x0, time 4580576, (1026,1334), root:(1076,1499),
    state 0x2010, keycode 104 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x16e, subw 0x0, time 4580669, (1026,1334), root:(1076,1499),
    state 0x2090, keycode 104 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

With help from @PRATAP:

- The output from xev means that keycode 104 is mapped to the keysm ISO_Level3_Shift
- Changing this assignment is easily done by running xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = KP_Enter"
- This xmodmap command sets the key association only until logging out
- So using Ubuntu's default "startup applications" interface, I added the command `sleep 10 && xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = KP_Enter"` to run each time I log in. At first this seems to work, but it is very unstable.  It almost seems like every time I want to use the keypad enter key, I have to first open a terminal and run `xmodmap`
- Recently I tried plugging a cheap Genius keyboard into a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine, and noted that the keypad enter worked out of the box.

So, my question: How do I get Keypad Enter to work?

Comment: @PRATAP done - I edited the question to contain the results.

Comment: @PRATAP When I run that xmodmap command you suggested, it works fine until I change the setting in Tweaks or reboot.  As soon as I do either of those two things, it reverts back to the way it was.

Comment: That works!  Do you want to type up the answer and I'll accept it?  I'm happy to do it if you prefer :)

Comment: Ah!  Sorry.  Ticking / unticking `enter on keypad` in Tweaks, does not change anything that I can detect.  I think the wording in Tweaks is maybe confusing it is: `key to choose 3rd level` -> `Enter on Keypad`.  Putting `xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = KP_Enter"` in startup applications works perfectly, and is very easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93309/discussion-between-johan-and-pratap).

Comment: `xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = KP_Enter"` does not work at all.  It is so unstable as to be unusable - to the point where EVERY SINGLE TIME I want to use the keypad enter key, I have to first open a terminal and run this command.  I'm deleting my answer, as it's no answer at all.  I'll move some of the relevant research into the question.